# How can I get a list of items in a Rally instance via the REST API?

Tags: rally

I want to get the list of items in the view lookup..but i just cant find what to query for that..i have tries everything but i just dont seem to get how to do it

I have even tried using

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.29/subscription.js?fetch=Workspaces,Projects,Name&pretty=true

but that only fetches me the worspace and projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by view lookup. In any case, it is not possible to query on all work items in a subscription. Here is an example of a query on all defects in a workspace, when  Name,FormattedID,State are being fetched:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/defect?workspace=https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/1111&fetch=Name,FormattedID,State
```

All queries on work items are workspace scoped. You do not have to provide workspace explicitly as in the example above. If you are currently logged in to Rally in another tab of the same browser the context is already set, and this endpoint will work too:

```
 https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/defect?&fetch=Name,FormattedID,State
```

You may want to narrow a scope by using a query parameter, e.g.

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/defect?&query=(State = Open)&fetch=Name,FormattedID
```

Also, v2.0 removed the ability to return child collections in the same response for performance reasons. Now fetching a collection will return an object with the count and the url from which to get the collection data:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/Subscription/7777/Workspaces
```

where 7777 is OID of the subscription.

If you want to replicate a query in a custom view in Rally UI, open the view to determine the conditions and then build a similar query. Here is an example of a query that imitates a custom view below:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement?query=((Blocked = true) AND (Owner.UserName = nick01@test.com))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks...But By view look up ,what i mean to get is all the values in the drop down named view...i will need the diff items cause i want to map them into another application.....I am new to this thing so probably am not using the correct terms

Comment: I added an example of replicating a custom view conditions in a query.